# Why Is System.Drawing Included in One ASP.NET Default Project?

Tags: asp.net

When you create a new empty One ASP.NET application in VS2013 the project includes a reference to `System.Drawing`. Removing this reference has no apparent side effects.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx)

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use
>   within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes
>   from within one of these application types may produce unexpected
>   problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time
>   exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging
>   Components.

Why is it included?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported within a SERVICE, that's the most important part of that paragraph. You're using an ASP.NET application, which is very different. System.Drawing is quite often used reference, so they've added it by default. When you're dealing with web applications, it's very common for image manipulation etc.

Comment: Well no, System.Drawing should not be used in an ASP.NET application at all. It is common but incorrect to use System.Drawing for image manipulation in an ASP.NET app, something many developers have had to learn the hard way.

Comment: Can you provide a relevant link to support that claim? I've used it numerous times without any issue.

Comment: You mean other than the MSDN article in the OP explicitly stating that it is not supported in ASP.NET?

Comment: @Paul, once again, read it properly - windows or asp.net SERVICE. That's not the same as APPLICATION.

Comment: "System.Drawing.* classes were designed for use with Windows Forms and were tested for use with Windows Forms. When we say they are not supported in services or ASP.NET applications (also a service), we mean exactly that; they are not supported."

Comment: But whatever, go ahead and use them if you want. The fact that System.Drawing.* classes should not be used in ASP.NET apps is well established elsewhere, and this has nothing to do with my question anyway.

Comment: @Paul, if you quote, show the link as well. There is no such sentence in the linked article ;-) I can quote like that all day long... And YES, it is related to the question, because it explains why it is referenced by default by the very same people who you no claim say the opposite.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2007/05/14/what-does-not-supported-mean.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaskis/archive/2012/03/23/why-you-should-not-use-system-drawing-from-asp-net-applications.aspx

Comment: Beyond the fact that non-trivial ASP.NET application shouldn't use System.Drawing, the logic here is flawed--you don't just throw unused assemblies into a project because they *might* be dependencies of another assembly. Furthermore, in One ASP.NET there is only one project type, so the idea of there being some kind of distinction between an ASP.NET 'application' or 'service' makes no sense at all. When you consider the architecture there is no reason to believe this guidance would apply to only certain types of ASP.NET apps.